# How to instantiting System.IO.StreamWriter using ANSI encoding on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, streamwriter

I have no experience on creating Power Shell scripts and I'm trying to instantiating System.IO.StreamWriter class providing a specific text encoding. I'm trying to do this:

```
$file = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter("sample.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default, 4096)
```

And I'm getting the following error message:

```
New-Object : Cannot find an overload for "StreamWriter" and the argument count: "3". 
At line:1 char:18 
    + $out = New-Object <<<<  System.IO.StreamWriter("sample.txt", [System.Text.Encoding]::Default, 4096)
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand
```

I looked at MSDN documentation [StreamWriter Constructor (Stream, Encoding, Int32)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/72d9f8d5%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) and it has an overload with three parameters.

Does anyone know how to instantiate a System.IO.StreamWriter specifiying an encoding?

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're trying to call `StreamWriter(String, Encoding, Int32)` - and *that* signature doesn't exist. Admittedly the error message leaves a little to be desired... but basically you'll either need to create the stream yourself, or using [`StreamWriter(String, Boolean, Encoding)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5f5x7kt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: The first ctor parameter is a Stream, not a String.

Comment: @JohnC: Exactly. But the first *argument* the OP is trying to pass is a String. That's my point.